# How to copy some columns from a table and put into a word file

Tags: excel, ms-word

[image]

Here is an example of a table. I want to be able to put the product name, sale price, qty sold and total profit of each item into a table on a word document, if the qty has a value. No idea how to start.

Would it also be possible to add this to the end of an existing word file?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution but it's definitely simple:

Activate filters, unselect "Blanks" from the Qty Sold column. Copy and paste the whole table into Word then right click to delete the columns you don't need.

Alternatively, if you already have the table worked up in Word, then you can select the individual columns you need and copy/paste only those.